# Sort X & Y by size

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, asort

I'm trying to figure out how to sort an array, that has sub arrays which each have an X & Y coordinate. I need to sort the largest size first to the smallest, example:

```
$sizes = array(
    'a' => array(
        'x' => 10,
        'y' => 140,
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'x' => 20,
        'y' => 24,
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'x' => 20,
        'y' => 40,
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'x' => 50,
        'y' => 50,
    ),
    'e' => array(
        'x' => 10,
        'y' => 9,
    ),
);
```

Should resort naturally like so:

```
$sizes = array(
    'e' => array(
        'x' => 10,
        'y' => 9,
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'x' => 20,
        'y' => 24,
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'x' => 20,
        'y' => 40,
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'x' => 50,
        'y' => 50,
    ),
    'a' => array(
        'x' => 10,
        'y' => 140,
    ),
);
```

I've sorted by value before using asort, however I'm not sure how to sort and maintain index association on a multidimensional array like this. Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried `uasort()`? Also, shouldn't `[10, 140]` be the second item?

Comment: Hi Jack, No I haven't, but 10 x 140 would actually be the largest, seeing as it's width is smaller, it would still take up the most area.

Comment: So, `uasort($sizes, function($a, $b) { return ($a['x'] * $a['y']) - ($b['x'] * $b['y']); });` then?

Comment: Thanks heaps for this jack, but why does the 10 x 140 end up second last?

Comment: Because 2500 > 1400.

Comment: I just changed the * to + as that's the result I'm looking for, but thankyou!

Comment: You mentioned area, which pretty much means width x height ... but whatever works for you.

Comment: Ah sorry, You are correct, but I did write the wrong thing, thankyou though!

Answer (score 0):

A great goto for me:

```
    function sort_multi_array_2_col($arrInbound
        , $strColumn1
        , $strColumn1Sort = "ASC"
        , $strColumn2
        , $strColumn2Sort = "ASC") {

        reset($arrInbound);

        foreach ($arrInbound as $key => $row) {
            $columnToSort1[$key] = $row[$strColumn1];
            $columnToSort2[$key] = $row[$strColumn2];
       }

        array_multisort($columnToSort1
            , get_sort_flag($strColumn1Sort)
            , $columnToSort2
            , get_sort_flag($strColumn2Sort)
            , $arrInbound);

        return $arrInbound;
  }

    function get_sort_flag($strSort) {

    if($strSort == "ASC"){
          return SORT_ASC;
      } else {
          return SORT_DESC;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Hi mate, what is get_sort_flag, this seems to be a function that doesn't exist for me?